# Dilemma: when to use Fragments vs Activities:

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-activity, architecture

I know that `Activities` are designed to represent a single screen of my application, while `Fragments` are designed to be reusable UI layouts with logic embedded inside of them.

Until not long ago, I developed an application as it said that they should be developed.
I created an `Activity` to represent a screen of my application and used Fragments for `ViewPager` or `Google Maps`. I rarely created a `ListFragment` or other UI that can be reused several times.

Recently I stumbled on a project that contains only 2 `Activities` one is a `SettingsActivity` and other one is the `MainActivity`. The layout of the `MainActivity` is populated with many hidden full screen UI fragments and only one is shown. In the `Activity` logic there are many `FragmentTransitions` between the different screens of the application.

What I like about this approach is that because the application uses an `ActionBar`, it stays intact and does not move with the screen switching animation, which is what happens with `Activity` switching. This give a more fluent feel to those screen transitions.

So I guess what I'm asking is to share your current development manner regarding this topic, I know it might look like an opinion based question at first look but I look at it as an Android design and architecture question... Not really an opinion based one.

**UPDATE (01.05.2014):** Following this presentation by **Eric Burke** from **Square**, (which I have to say is a great presentation with a lot of useful tools for android developers. And I am not related in any way to Square)

http://www.infoq.com/presentations/Android-Design/

From my personal experience over the past few months, I found that the best way to construct my applications is to create groups of fragments that come to represent a **flow** in the application and present all those fragments in one `Activity`. So basically you will have the same number of `Activities` in your application as the number of flows.
That way the action bar stays intact on all the flow's screens, but is being recreated on changing a flow which makes a lot of sense. As Eric Burke states and as I have come to realize as well, the philosophy of using as few `Activities` as possible is not applicable for all situations because it creates a mess in what he calls the "God" activity.

Comment: Check out my post at SO - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24647078/android-activity-fragment-responsibilities-for-data-loading/24647574#24647574

Comment: Possible duplicate of [When should I use fragments in Android applications ? Why to use fragments?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8597769/when-should-i-use-fragments-in-android-applications-why-to-use-fragments)

Comment: Single Activity: Why, When, and How (Android Dev Summit '18) https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2k8x8V77CrU&feature=youtu.be

Comment: today, the best answer for this question is learning about SingleActivityArchitecture

Answer (score 308):

Experts will tell you: "When I see the UI, I will know whether to use an `Activity` or a `Fragment`". In the beginning this will not have any sense, but in time, you will actually be able to tell if you need `Fragment` or not.

There is a good practice I found very helpful for me. It occurred to me while I was trying to explain something to my daughter.

Namely, imagine a box which represents a screen. Can you load another screen in this box? If you use a new box, will you have to copy multiple items from the 1st box? If the answer is Yes, then you should use `Fragments`, because the root `Activity` can hold all duplicated elements to save you time in creating them, and you can simply replace parts of the box.

But **don't forget** that you always need a box container (`Activity`) or your parts will be dispersed. So one box with parts inside.

Take care not to misuse the box. Android UX experts advise (you can find them on YouTube) when we should explicitly load another `Activity`, instead to use a `Fragment` (like when we deal with the Navigation Drawer which has categories). Once you feel comfortable with `Fragments`, you can watch all their videos. Even more they are mandatory material.

Can you right now look at your UI and figure out if you need an `Activity` or a `Fragment`? Did you get a new perspective? I think you did.

Comment: do you have a link to the youtube feed you mentioned? I search for "Android UX experts" and "Android UX" but am not entirely sure which videos you're talking about.

Comment: Not any more, watched it over a year ago. Search for Android developer official talking about UX

Comment: One example of consideration: activity has parentActivity so we can synthesize backstack while entering from notification, but I don't think there's such parentFragment.

Comment: @BornToCode there is getParentFragment: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/Fragment#getparentfragment

Comment: @ToolmakerSteve yes it's getParentFragment, but it's not what I meant dude, see https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element#parent

Answer (score 154):

My philosophy is this:

Create an activity only if it's absolutely absolutely required. With the back stack made available for committing bunch of fragment transactions, I try to create as few activities in my app as possible. Also, communicating between various fragments is much easier than sending data back and forth between activities.

Activity transitions are expensive, right? At least I believe so - since the old activity has to be destroyed/paused/stopped, pushed onto the stack, and then the new activity has to be created/started/resumed.

It's just my philosophy since fragments were introduced.

Comment: true, but as you've written, sometimes it is needed to use activities. one example is a camera screen, where it's better to use it in landscape mode. another example is the configuration screen that is shown when you put a customized appWidget (on the "desktop"- the launcher app).

Comment: Thanks for you answer and sharing you experience So you think it's a good practice in android to limit application to one Activity and use Fragment for all screen if the application architecture permits it?

Comment: @EmilAdz Yeah. I think so. Limit your app to use as minimum activities as possible - architect it in such a way if possible.

Comment: Then how do you solve the issue of fragments needing to pass eachother "state"? All of the state across all of your fragments need to live in the one activity, otherwise you're forced to use a singleton.

Comment: I'm not convinced that communicating between various fragments is much easier rather than sending data back and forth between activities.

Comment: At least, `onActivityResult()` is safer and easer than fragments' callbacks.

Answer (score 72):

Well, according to Google's lectures (maybe [**here**](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=amZM8oZBgfk), I don't remember) , you should consider using Fragments whenever it's possible, as it makes your code easier to maintain and control.

However, I think that on some cases it can get too complex, as the activity that hosts the fragments need to navigate/communicate between them.

I think you should decide by yourself what's best for you. It's usually not that hard to convert an activity to a fragment and vice versa.

I've created a post about this dillema [**here**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10478233/android-need-some-clarifications-of-fragments-vs-activities-and-views), if you wish to read some further.

Comment: Thanks for you answer and sharing you experience So you think it's a good practice in android to limit application to one Activity and use Fragment for all screen if the application architecture permits it?

Comment: It depends on the project, but if it gets too complicated to you, you can separate to multiple activities too. Don't be afraid to use any of the methods. You could also use them both. Maybe sometimes it would be too hard for you to use fragments instead of activities. I think you should try to use fragments, but don't force it to be everywhere if it gets too much in your way...

Comment: what if I want to keep this affect of the ActionBar staying intact and all the content is being switched? Is it possible to achieve this with Activities?

Comment: What the Fragment? https://youtu.be/k3IT-IJ0J98?list=PLOU2XLYxmsILe6_eGvDN3GyiodoV3qNSC

Answer (score 45):

Since [Jetpack](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/), **Single-Activity app** is the preferred architecture. Usefull especially with the [Navigation Architecture Component](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/navigation/).

[source](http://android-developers.googleblog.com/2018/05/use-android-jetpack-to-accelerate-your.html)

Comment: I read about Jetpack for the first time today. :) We build single activity apps since fragments were introduced. Multi activity is much more complicated.

Comment: @TheincredibleJan You are right, Single Activity App architecture was better solution long before Jetpack

Answer (score 34):

Why I prefer Fragment over Activity in ALL CASES.

- Activity is expensive. In Fragment, views and property states are separated - whenever a fragment is in `backstack`, its views will be destroyed. So you can stack much more Fragments than Activity.
- `Backstack` manipulation. With `FragmentManager`, it's easy to clear all the Fragments, insert more than on Fragments and etcs. But for Activity, it will be a nightmare to manipulate those stuff.
- A much predictable *lifecycle*. As long as the host Activity is not recycled. the Fragments in the backstack will not be recycled. So it's possible to use `FragmentManager::getFragments()` to find specific Fragment (not encouraged).

Comment: HI, I read your review about the advantages of Frag over Act, Do you have any project to show the same in your Github Repo?

Answer (score 15):

In my opinion it's not really relevant. The key factor to consider is

1. how often are you gonna reuse parts of the UI (menus for example),
2. is the app also for tablets?

The main use of fragments is to build multipane activities, which makes it perfect for Tablet/Phone responsive apps.

Comment: I would say the main use of fragments is to make custom views without thinking of them as custom views. that's what happens anyways.

Fragments we're originally shown from Google as a handy way to make tablet responsive apps, so you could stick them in different activities if you wanted. a way to attach code to a view, more or less, and have them stickable where you want(without making custom views).

Answer (score 13):

Don't forget that an activity is application's block/component which can be shared and started through Intent! So each activity in your application should solve only one kind of task. If you have only one task in your application then I think you need only one activity and many fragments if needed. Of course you can reuse fragments in future activities which solve another tasks. This approach will be clear and logical separation of tasks. And you no need to maintain one activity with different intent filter parameters for different sets of fragments. You define tasks at the design stage of the development process based on requirements.

Comment: In our applications the one kind of task of the activity is to hold the navigation drawer to enter the different fragments. :) Why should I grapple with intents for fragments? It's clear and logical to hold a static reference to a "global" data class for global data and pass some values to a create instance method of a fragment.

Answer (score 10):

There's more to this than you realize, you have to remember than an activity that is launched does not implicitly destroy the calling activity. Sure, you can set it up such that your user clicks a button to go to a page, you start that page's activity and destroy the current one. This causes a lot of overhead. The best guide I can give you is:

** Start a new activity only if it makes sense to have the main activity and this one open at the same time (think of multiple windows).

A great example of when it makes sense to have multiple activities is Google Drive. The main activity provides a file explorer. When a file is opened, a new activity is launched to view that file. You can press the recent apps button which will allow you to go back to the browser without closing the opened document, then perhaps even open another document in parallel to the first.

Comment: Re *"Start a new activity only if it makes sense to have the main activity and this one open at the same time (think of multiple windows)."* I don't think so. That situation is well solved using *fragments* `attach`/`detach` methods.

Answer (score 9):

Thing I did: Using less fragment when possible. Unfortunately, it's possible in almost case. So, I end up with a lot of fragments and a little of activities.
Some drawbacks I've realized:

- `ActionBar` & Menu: When 2 fragment has different title, menu, that
     will hard to handle. Ex: when adding new fragment, you can change action bar title, but when pop it from `backstack` there is no way to restore the old title. You may need an Toolbar in every fragment for this case, but let believe me, that will spend you more time.
- When we need `startForResult`, activity has but fragment hasn't.
- Don't have transition animation by default

My solution for this is using an Activity to *wrap* a fragment inside. So we have separate action bar, menu, `startActivityForResult`, animation,...

Comment: Very useful points, thanks. Can you clarify "*an Activity to wrap a fragment*"? Did you make a separate Activity for each fragment? If so, do you need Fragment at all?

Comment: there is a way to restore title and stuff. use `getSupportFragmentManager().addOnBackStackChangedListener` to add a listener. get current fragment in that listener and then set title and stuff.

Answer (score 6):

The one big advantage of a `fragment` over activity is that , the code which is used for fragment can be used for different activities. So, it provides *re-usability* of code in application development.

Comment: How? COuld you provide some example please?

Comment: @sofs1 Your question doesn't make much sense. Any code in a fragment remains the same no matter from which activity the fragment is instatiated.

Comment: @TheincredibleJan But couldn't we also say "Any code in an activity remains the same no matter from which activity the second activity is instantiated."? I don't see the difference.

Answer (score 5):

use one activity per application to provide base for `fragment` 
use `fragment` for screen , 
`fragments` are *lite weight* as compared to `activites`
fragments are *reusable* 
fragments are *better suited* for app which support both phone & tablet

Answer (score 3):

You are free to use one of those. 
Basically, you have to evaluate which is the best one to your app. Think about how you will manage the business flow and how to store/manage data preferences.

Think about, how Fragments store garbage data. When you implement the fragment, you have a activity root to fill with fragment(s). So, if your trying to implement a lot of activities with too much fragments, you have to consider performance on your app, coz you're manipulating (coarsely speaks) two context lifecycle, remember the complexity.

Remember: should I use fragments? Why shouldn't I?

regards.

Answer (score 2):

I use Fragments for better user experience. For example if you have a Button and you want to run let's say a webservice when you click it, I attach a Fragment to the parent Activity.

```
if (id == R.id.forecast) {

    ForecastFragment forecastFragment = new ForecastFragment();
    FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();
    FragmentTransaction ft = fm.beginTransaction();
    ft.replace(R.id.main_content, forecastFragment);
    ft.addToBackStack("backstack");
    forecastFragment.setArguments(b);
    ft.commit();
}
```

In that way the user won't have to move in another activity.

And secondly I prefer Fragments because you can handle them easily during rotation.

Comment: What makes that example a better user experience? How will they know (or care) that they're doing an activity or a fragment?

Answer (score 2):

It depends what you want to build really. For example the `navigation drawer` uses fragments. Tabs use `fragments` as well. Another good implementation,is where you have a `listview`. When you rotate the phone and click a row the activity is shown in the remaining half of the screen. Personally,I use `fragments` and `fragment dialogs`,as it is more professional. Plus they are handled easier in rotation.

Answer (score 1):

**Some wrong ideas:**

- Always put an **activity** in your app and handle different screens with **fragments**.
- Write the **UI** code directly in the **activity**.
- Handle **navigating** between screens (I don't mean tabs, I mean for example full-screen views) by **fragments**.
- **Activities** can be replaced by **fragments**.

**Here is the thing!**

Fragments are designed to implement reusable parts of UI and use them in any part of the app that is needed. They are not designed for substituting activities.

**When we must use each of them?**

- When we have an **independent screen** in which there are some **different UI parts** (tabs, expandable screens, partial screens, etc...) we should use **an activity with some fragments** to implement and handle different UI parts separately in the same screen.
- Each **independent part** of the application is actually a **component** that is **conceptually different** from other parts and it needs to have an **independent activity**. For example, the **login** part may contain some **different scenarios** like using username-password or using fingerprint. Each scenario can be implemented by a fragment and all login-related fragments should be handled by **LoginActivity**. But for example, the part of the **orders** in the application doesn't have a **conceptual relationship** with login, so it must have a different activity and of course, it may contain some fragments like OrdersFragment, SubmitNewOrderFragment, and etc that all of them must be managed by **OrdersActivity**.
- **Do not implement** a UI directly in an activity. Always implement UI in fragments and add those fragments in the activity even if there is only one fragment in that activity. It helps you to have more reusable code and change UIs easier.
- **Never use fragments to navigate infinitely** in the application even if you force the user to have a limited number of fragments in the back stack. The fact is that when you add a new fragment into the back stack and remove it, it will not be removed from the memory unless the parent activity gets destroyed and it is only not visible. So when you are using fragment manager back stack, by navigating multiple times between fragments in the same activity (especially in the case of you create a new fragment on each navigation and put them into the back stack) you will get an **OutOfMemoryException** in the application.

I hope it to be helpful.

Comment: Since Jetpack Compose's release, I see no reason for using Fragments anymore. All UI is reusable by design and a single-activity app is the best choice. Simply swap the UI through some state inside a when statement, and maybe even wrap it inside AnimatedContent to add transitions.

Answer (score 0):

Almost always use fragments. If you know that the app you are building will remain very small, the extra effort of using fragments may not be worth it, so they can be left out. For larger apps, the complexity introduced is offset by the flexibility fragments provide, making it easier to justify having them in the project.
Some people are very opposed to the additional complexity involved with fragments and their lifecycles, so they never use them in their projects. An issue with this approach is that there are several APIs in Android that rely on fragments, such as ViewPager and the Jetpack Navigation library. If you need to use these options in your app, then you must use fragments to get their benefits.

Excerpt From: Kristin Marsicano. “Android Programming: The Big Nerd Ranch Guide, 4th Edition.” Apple Books.

Answer (score 0):

This question needs to be reevaluated since `Jetpack Compose` has reached stable.

> Jetpack Compose is Android’s recommended modern toolkit for building
> native UI.
>
> from https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose

The typical jetpack-compose architecture is:
Single Activity, multiple composables, and glued together by jetpack navigation.
Note there's no (need for) Fragments anymore.

See [Now in Android](https://github.com/android/nowinandroid) for a sample.