# Android activity/fragment responsibilities for data loading

Tags: android

When starting a new application for a client, I am asking myself again the same question about who should be responsible for loading data: activities or fragments. I have taken both options for various apps and I was wondering which pattern is best according to you in terms of:

- limiting the code complexity.
- handling edge cases (like screen rotation, screen going power save, loss of connectivity, etc.)

#### Option 1 - Activity loads data & fragment only displays it

This allows to have fragments that are just fed a bunch of objects to display. They know nothing about loading data and how we load that.

On the other side, the activity loads data using whichever method is required (for instance initially the latest 50 entries and on a search, loads the search result). It then passes it to the fragment which displays it. Method to load the data could be anything (from service, from DB, ... fragments only know about POJOs)

It's kind of a MVC architecture where the activity is the controller and fragments are the view.

#### Option 2 - Activity arranges fragments & fragments are responsible to fetch the data

In this pattern, fragments are autonomous pieces of application. They know how to load the data they are displaying and how to show it to the user.

Activities are simply a way to arrange fragments on screen and to coordinate transitions between application activities.

Comment: I would prefer option 1, because fragment life-cycle always call onCreateView even after resuming that means loading the data again. But loading the data once in a activity it can be easily rendered on the fragment. And passing the data among fragment can also achieved easily.

Comment: I put my view specific logic on the fragment and the common logic on the activity.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Ideally neither `Activity` nor `Fragment` **with UI** should contain any "model" logic - these classes should be lightweight and responsible only for UI logic. But when you decide to make a separate model object you have a dilemma to choose where to initialise and store this object and how to deal with configuration changes. And here comes some handy trick:

You can create a **model** `Fragment` **without UI**, make it [retain instance](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment.html#setRetainInstance(boolean)) to deal with configuration changes (it's AFAIK the simplest way to save data across config. changes without troubles) and retrieve it anywhere you need via `findFragmentById()`. You make all expensive operations inside it once (using background thread, of course), store your data and you're done.
For more info, see [Adding a fragment without a UI](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html#Adding) section.

**UPD**: There's now a better way to deal with configuration changes: [ViewModel](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/viewmodel.html) from [Google's Architecture Components](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/index.html). Here's [a good example](https://blog.stylingandroid.com/architecture-components-viewmodel/).

Comment: This is how I ended up doing it. Provides a very clear separation of who does what. And using the Otto library (or any event bus library you like) helps to keep everything separated as communication happens via an event bus. Thanks for the input.

Answer (score 18):

In theory you can do whatever you want, if it works. 
Actually, the fragments and activities display data and deal with their own life cycles.

Since fragments belongs to activity so you have to use both in conjunction to better handle all the data but mostly it depends on your needs.

If you keep in mind the idea that the Fragment should provide the UI and the Activity should provide the processing then you have a good division of concerns and code which should allow the Fragment or the Activity to be reused.

If you know about the **MVC - Model View Controller** - design pattern then you can think of the Fragment as the View and the Activity as the Model.

Things get much more interesting when you build an application with multiple Fragments.

**Some key points as a decide factor -**

- *The idea of a Fragment is that it is a wrapped up chunk of UI that
  can be used by any Activity that needs it. On this basis you have to
  ask yourself if the event that has to be handled is the same for
  every Activity or unique to each Activity. If it is the same then the
  event handler is better written within the Fragment.*
- *The Fragment doesn't have a UI of its own - it is displayed by an
  Activity  that the Fragment is associated with. The events are
  generated by objects in the View hierarchy, which is owned by the
  Activity. If you try to use Android Studio to add an event handler,
  for example, it will add it to the Activity and not to the Fragment.*
- *You can define the `EventListener` that you want to handle the event
  in the Fragment and then hook it up to the View object in the
  Activity in which you want to generate the event.*
- *A Fragment is a class that implements the `onCreateView` method to
  supply a View hierarchy that can be displayed by an Activity.*
- *To use a Fragment in an Activity you have to add it using a
  FragmentManager and a FragmentTransaction. You can add the Fragment
  using the add method but nothing happens until you call the commit
  method.*
- *After the method that used the commit, usually the Activity's
  onCreate, terminates the CreateView event runs the Fragment's
  onCreateView and the Fragments View hierarchy is added to the
  Activity's content.*
- *You have to write code to save and restore any additional state the
  Fragment may have.*
- *If a task is common to all instances of the Fragment then its code
  should live in the Fragment.*
- *In particular the code to handle events can be defined within the
  Fragment.*
- *The Activity should be used to host code that processes the data
  provided by the UI.*
- *Attaching Activity event handlers to the Fragment's UI or is
  difficult to do correctly.*
- *From scenarios make decision what your app will be. Is it service,
  activity, widget , even a content provider or a complex system,
  including some different components. Test your decision against
  scenarios.*
- *All of these have to work after the Fragment has been destroyed and
  recreated.*

  *(1) `Initialization of the Fragment`, (2) `Saving and restoring the Fragment's 
  state` and  (3) `Implementing something like an event mechanism so the Fragment 
  can get the Activity's attention`*

  *The hardest part is implementing something like an event mechanism.*
- *In the case of the complex system, distribute functionalities and
  data entities among application components. Make a list of components
  and what they are (activities or smth else).*
- *Make the list of UI components with description what they do (not HOW
  yet) These will be widgets and activities or fragments or layouts
  later.*
- *Often you will want one Fragment to communicate with another, for example 
  to change the  content based on a user event. All Fragment-to-Fragment
  communication is  done through the associated Activity. Two Fragments 
  should never communicate directly.*
- *When your app is perfectly modular, fragments don't know about each
  other. You can add a fragment, remove a fragment, replace a fragment,
  and they should all work fine, because they are all independent, and
  the activity has full control over the configuration.*
- *You can't do anything with a Fragment unless you start a transaction.
  Within the transaction you can set up what you want to happen,
  usually add the Fragment to the current layout, but nothing happens
  until you use the commit method.*

**Efficient handling of data with Screen Orientation -**

*When screen orientation changes, Android restarts the running Activity (`onDestroy()` is called, followed by `onCreate()`).*

To properly handle a restart, it is important that your activity restores its previous state through the normal Activity lifecycle, in which Android calls `onSaveInstanceState()` before it destroys your activity so that you can save data about the application state. You can then restore the state during `onCreate()` or `onRestoreInstanceState()`.

However, you might encounter a situation in which restarting your application and restoring significant amounts of data can be costly and create a poor user experience. In such a situation, you have two other options:

**1)** ***Retain an object during a configuration change***

*Allow your activity to restart when a configuration changes, but carry a stateful Object to the new instance of your activity.*

**2)** ***Handle the configuration change yourself***

*Prevent the system from restarting your activity during certain configuration changes, but receive a callback when the configurations do change, so that you can manually update your activity as necessary.*

What I would do is manage all data flow (`bluetooth, database storage, etc`) 
in the Activity and use Fragments only for UI display or handling user input.

This way is easier to handle configuration changes/ screen rotations.

Also, if data flow things are heavy to be on UI thread, consider using a `Service` with a background thread. 
If it is a "one shot" thing, you can use an `IntentService`, 
otherwise you can implement a `Bind Service` and request a bind from anywhere you have Context.

For more read - [fragment-and-activity-working-together](http://www.i-programmer.info/programming/android/6996-fragment-and-activity-working-together.html).

Answer (score 2):

I prefer and always implemented Option-2 over Option-1.

**Reasons for not selecting Option-1:**

1. We should have listeners for events triggered in Fragments and pass it back to activity to load data, process it and push it back to fragment, which makes work more complex.
2. An Activty can load any number of Fragments, Typically you end up *questioning these questions to yourself* in a scenario **where your app is highly scalable** and **is already huge**. Writing all the events in an activity and passing it over to fragment will be an complex altogether.
3. As @Ved Prakash mentioned, Handling screen orientation becomes complex if orientation is handled by Activty.

Comment: I have an activity with frame layout for fragment and one button for static categories alert dialog box.by default load one category of data on that frame layout using fragment.if user select on new category on the categories button pass that value to server and get response and i need to populate latest response also that same frame layout with existing fragment.please give some suggetions for one fragemnt with dynamica data based on the selected item.

Answer (score 0):

I have an example:
your application have 2 features A and B. the 2 features are independent each other. and each feature has a lot of screen.
you should create 2 activities A and B because when Activity A is used, Activity B should be released to reduce memory of app. And the same when B is used, A should be released. The memory of Context A and B are independent, if you want to send data from Activity A to B you must use intent or use global variable in Application Context. intent is managed by OS, not by application. When A send intent to B, if A is destroy is no problem with intent send to B. Activity is App module, it is can call by other applications (fragment is impossible).

for example: feature A has a lot of screen (ex: Fragment1, Fragment2). they use the same data and depend on each other. each screen should be a fragment. and when process with data you can get reference to data by calling function getActivity()  and then get reference to variable of Activity context (or Activity memory) to write or read it. Fragment1 and Fragment2 are belong to Activity A Context.it means that Fragment 1 and Fragment 2 can transfer data with each other via variable of Activity context, it is easy to do . noticed that Intent is managed by OS,it is so expensive when send data via Intent.