# When to make a fragment vs an activity in my small android application?

Tags: android, android-activity, fragment

I am trying to create an android project and I have a few questions about what is proper practice.

I have a navigation drawer fragment that I use to navigate around my application.

I am trying to make a login fragment, but I can't find much information on how to do that, but there is information on a login activity.  Is it improper for me to make a login activity?

I also want to add a form and a map to my app.  Before I decided to add the navigation drawer I was using an activity for each of those but now I am confused whether I should be doing that... Or does it make more sense to have a form fragment that gets information from a map activity?

I know the fragment vs activity question has been asked before ([Dilemma: when to use Fragments vs Activities:](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20306091/dilemma-when-to-use-fragments-vs-activities)) but I am still unsure if this is what I should be doing.

any guidance would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A common explanation of Fragments, and one I sometimes even use myself, is:
**Fragments groups user interface components and their associated logic.**

please check the following link for knowing ,where you can apply it exactly.

http://blog.pluralsight.com/android-fragments

Comment: Thanks!  The last time I developed for android everything was an activity and it's been confusing switching to using fragments.