# Switch activity/fragment with bottom navigation

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-activity

I created an activity with a bottom navigation bar.
I googled a lot things about it but now I don't know how to handle this exactly.
Before, I just started another activity when the user clicks the bottom navigation but I think it's not good.

How can I switch between the tabs?
Do I have to work with fragments? And what about 'setContentView(int layoutResID)'? How can I do that? I'm confused...

```
private BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener mOnNavigationItemSelectedListener = new BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {

    @Override
    public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.navigation_home:
                return true;
            case R.id.navigation_dashboard:
                startActivity(dashboardActivity);
                return true;
            case R.id.navigation_notifications:
                startActivity(dashboardActivity);
                return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

};
```

Thank you very much for your help - I hope, you understood what I mean.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Activity transition is always expensive and we should switch from one activity to another only when we are switching the context. A `fragment` is  a portion of UI in an activity. Same fragment can be used with multiple activities. Just like activity a fragment has its own lifecycle and  `setContentView(int layoutResID)` can be set to different layout in  `OnCreate` of fragment.

This [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20306091/dilemma-when-to-use-fragments-vs-activities) explains more on when to use activity or fragment.

[Android developer guide on Fragments](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html)

[Code path tutorial](https://guides.codepath.com/android/Bottom-Navigation-Views) on bottom navigation views.

Answer (score 2):

Please refer to :-

https://github.com/waleedsarwar86/BottomNavigationDemo

and complete explanation in

http://waleedsarwar.com/posts/2016-05-21-three-tabs-bottom-navigation/

You will get a running code with the explanation here.

Answer (score 1):

Bottom Navigation View is a navigation bar introduced in android library to make it easy to switch between views with a single tap. It can although be used for almost any purpose, but is most commonly used to switch between fragments with a single tap. Its use for opening activities is somewhat absurd, since it ignores its most important functionality of **switching the views with a single tap**. There are many good articles and blogs out there in this regard, one of which is:
https://medium.com/@hitherejoe/exploring-the-android-design-support-library-bottom-navigation-drawer-548de699e8e0
Hope this solves your doubt..

Answer (score 0):

```
bottomNavigationView.setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener
                (new BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {
                    @Override
                    public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
                        Fragment selectedFragment = null;
                        switch (item.getItemId()) {
                            case R.id.action_item1:
                                selectedFragment = ItemOneFragment.newInstance();
                                FragmentTransaction transaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                                transaction.replace(R.id.frame_layout, selectedFragment);
                                transaction.commit();
                                // selectedFragment.getChildFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                                break;

                            case R.id.action_item2:
                                selectedFragment = ItemTwoFragment.newInstance();
                                FragmentTransaction transactiona = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                                transactiona.replace(R.id.frame_layout, selectedFragment);
                                transactiona.commit();
                              //  selectedFragment = ItemThreeFragment.newInstance();
                                break;

                            case R.id.action_item3:
                            //  selectedFragment = ItemOneFragment.newInstance();
                                Intent intent=new Intent(MainView.this, YoutActivityLive.class);
                                intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                                startActivity(intent);
                               // selectedFragment = ItemTwoFragment.newInstance();
                                break;


                            case R.id.action_item5:
                                selectedFragment = ItemOneFragment.newInstance();
                                FragmentTransaction transactionb = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                                transactionb.replace(R.id.frame_layout, selectedFragment);
                                transactionb.commit();
                               // selectedFragment = ItemFiveFragment.newInstance();
                                break;
                        }

                        return true;
                    }
                });
```

Comment: From Review:  Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please don't answer just with source code. Try to provide a nice description about how your solution works. See: [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). Thanks