# Dynamically change the fragment at the state already login and haven't login

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have an application that allows the user to use the apps without login (and with login too of course).

When the user hasn't logged in, I want my apps to show a fragment which asks the user to login (LoginFragment).
And when the user already logged in, I want my apps to show the main fragment (HomeFragment).

I use firebase auth as my login "functionality".
Here is my MainActivity code.

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    mMainFrame = findViewById(R.id.main_frame);
    mMainNav = findViewById(R.id.main_nav);

    homeFragment = new HomeFragment();
    measureFragment = new MeasureFragment();
    accountFragment = new AccountFragment();
    loginFragment = new LoginFragment();

    setFragment(measureFragment);

    mMainNav.setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener(new BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
            switch (item.getItemId()){
                case R.id.nav_measure:
                    setFragment(measureFragment);
                    return true;
                case R.id.nav_home:
                    mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
                    mAuthListener = new FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onAuthStateChanged(@NonNull FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth) {
                            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "1", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            user = firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser();
                            if (user != null) {
                                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "2", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                setFragment(homeFragment);
                            } else {
                                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "3", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                setFragment(loginFragment);
                            }
                        }
                    };
                    return true;
                case R.id.nav_account:
                    setFragment(accountFragment);
                    return true;
                    default:
                        return false;
            }
        }
    });
}

private void setFragment(Fragment fragment) {
    FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
    fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.main_frame , fragment);
    fragmentTransaction.commit();
}
```

Here is my mockup

1. if the user haven't log in
   [User haven't log in, the "LoginFragment" is showed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a9foJ.png)
2. if the user already login
   [User already login, the "HomeFragment" is showed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YRz0T.png)

Comment: Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50705537/7671879) type of approach.

Comment: I already use that kind of approach, but my code is not working. I need a code solution

Comment: What is not working? By what i can see in your code, you are replacing the previous fragment, and by this your back press won't make you return to the previous screen/fragment.